# Do standard library containers structures store copies or references?

Tags: c++, std

I'm afraid that standard library containers store inside themselves copies of all elements that I push into them. I hoped that they worked with references or pointers to my elements, so they don't waste extra memory and time making copies of each element. I made this proof:

```
queue<int> prueba;

int x = 5;
prueba.push(x);

x++;

cout << prueba.front() << ", ";
cout << x;

prueba.pop();
```

And the result was: 5, 6.

So, If I make a big class with a lot of heavy members, and then, I push a lot of objects of that class into a standard library container.

Will containers make a copy of each object inside? That's terrible!

Is there any way to avoid this catastrophic end, other than create just containers of pointers?

Comment: Yes, they make copies. That is the concept behind it. Otherwise, you couldn't actually return a e.g. `vector` without everything stored in it becoming invalid.

Comment: Also, since C++11, many containers have a sort of construct-in-place mechanic (e.g `emplace_back` for `vector`) which attacks this problem of making unnecessary copies.

Comment: If the object is inside the container then why do you need another copy outside the container.  The container owns the object.

Comment: If you want them to store pointers, define them as being collections of (prefereably smart) pointers.

Comment: What if you'd put `int x=5; prueba.push(x);` inside a function.  What would you expect `prueba.front()` to do after the function had returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Does STL structures stores copies or references?

## C++ standard containers are non-instrusive containers

and as such they have the following properties:

> Object doesn't "know" and contain details about the container in which is to be stored. Example:
>
> ```
> struct Node
> {
>     T data;
> }
> ```
>
> #### 1. Pros:
>
> - does not containe additional information regarding the container integration.
> - object's lifetime managed by the container. (less complex.)
>
> #### 2. Cons:
>
> - **store copies of values passed by the user.** (inplace `emplace` construction possible.)
> - an object can belong only to one container. (or the contaier should store pointers to objects.)
> - overhead on storing copies. (bookkeeping on each allocation.)
> - can't store derived object and still maintain its original type. (slicing - looses polymorphism.)

Thus, the answer to your question is - they store copies.

> 2. Is there any way to avoid this catastrophic end, other than create just containers of pointers?

As far as I know, a reasonable solution is container of smart pointers.

Comment: Another reasonable solution is to use inplace construction and move semantics to avoid copying.

Comment: @spectras you are probably right, I mostly tried to cover the "container part" of the question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is simple: STL containers store copies.